# What modifications should I do before reapplication after this kind of visa rejection?

Tags: visa, canada, student-visa

I applied for a Canadian student visa. After a month, I got a rejection saying that "**Your proposed studies are not reasonable in light of one or more of: your qualifications, previous studies, missing marks sheets, academic record, level of establishment, language abilities, or your future prospects and plans**".

I am a physics graduate applied for master in mathematics. Can this be one of the reasons?
My question is should I upload all my transcripts and certificates from school, take a written letter from the McMaster professor stating that I qualify for the program, write a personal statement while reapplying?

What should be there in the personal statement? I don't know what "level of establishment" means. Please let me know asap. Thanks in advance.

[image: Visa Rejection]

Comment: The letter clearly states that you are being rejected on one or more of those reasons. The first step should be to pinpoint the exact reason for your rejection. You should look at your application and understand where the problem is or take it to a visa consultant

Comment: I don't think ur qualification is a problem. It might be missing mark sheets, academic record or language abilities. Did you do well on your IELTS or TOEFL

Comment: I have a TOEFL score of 95. And what do they mean by "level of establishment"? @TheLastWord

Comment: Level of establishment is how well your family (parents, siblings) is doing in your country of residence, financially and socially, indicated by jobs, property, income, businesses etc.

Comment: @TheLastWord Unless someone else wrote this question, I would be surprised if language skills were the reason.  Subhajit Mishra: I also suspect that a physics graduate desiring to study mathematics is fairly normal, and that this has little or nothing to do with the refusal. Of course, the subjective items such as "future prospects and plans" could be implicated for reasons other than the physics/mathematics "discrepancy."  But Martin Argerami's answer seems the most plausible explanation at this point.

Comment: Hi Im in a similar situation,but Im a bachelor degree holder of Computer application now I would like to change it to Health care assistant.I have gained acceptance in university. What should I do.
The feedback I got from visa officer is same as above. And my IELTS score is 7.0

Comment: @RenitaSweety Yours is a new question. Please ask new questions by using an "Ask Question" button, found on the top right of all SE pages.

Answer (score 2):

You write that you "applied" for an MSc in math. I would expect a candidate to apply for a visa after being officially admitted, that's the way I've seen it happen with all our graduate students. The official letter of admission is a key part of the visa  application.

The only cases I know of rejections are those where the admission letter did not contain a funding offer and the candidate was not able to prove the availability of funding of their own.